# Selecting from same class the first child and adding a class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have two classes with nested content, ex:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class='tab-pane'></div>
  <div class='tab-pane'></div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class='tab-pane'></div>
  <div class='tab-pane'></div>
</div>
```

How do I add the class active on the first `tab-pane` for each `tab-content`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5e31020e/)

```
$(".tab-content").each(function() {
  $(this).children(".tab-pane").first().addClass("active");
});
```

---

Could also do this with a more specific selector:

```
$(".tab-content > .tab-pane:first-child").addClass("active");
```

Comment: @Anubhab our anwsers work too... This is not the only anwser that works.. So he can accept my anwser or Anubab anwser to....  Somone is raging over the down.

Comment: @AmanuelBogale, multiple working answers doesn't mean one should get a downvote. Also, this was the first working answer. Someone is raging with the down :)

Comment: @AmanuelBogale, ya but the user who originally asked the question got his problem solved evidently from his comment!! Its his decision.

Comment: This is funny... anyway it doesn't really matter that much; I just get curious when someone downvotes for seemingly no reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add to the first `tab-pane` of both the `tab-content` classes - you could do

```
$('.tab-content').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.tab-pane').eq(0).addClass('active');//.first() instead of .eq(0) will also work. eq() just gives you more controll 
});
```

Basically looping over each of your class .tab-content - then selecting necessory child.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class='tab-pane'></div>
<div class='tab-pane'></div>
</div>

 <div class="tab-content">
<div class='tab-pane'></div>
<div class='tab-pane'></div>
</div>
```

For that you can see that all of them are in the class tab-content. So you can select that by jquery then find the children of class .tab-pane and then find the **first** child, and then finnaly add class Active!

```
$(".tab-content").each(function() {
    $(".tab-content").children(".tab-pane").first().addClass("active");
})
```

And in css..

```
.active{
color:blue
}
```

### Snipet

```js
$(".tab-content").each(function() {
  $(this).children(".tab-pane").first().addClass("active");
  //This wont work: $(".tab-content").children(".tab-pane").first().addClass("active");
  //You can check if you want..
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class='tab-pane'>1</div>
  <div class='tab-pane'>2</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class='tab-pane'>1</div>
  <div class='tab-pane'>2</div>
</div>
```

You have to use $(this) because like what @seammy said...

> You changed to an each loop but then you aren't using this, you are
>   just setting the first tab-pane within a tab-content multiple times...
>   rather than for each tab-content

Comment: You changed to an each loop but then you aren't using `this`, you are just setting the first `tab-pane` within a `tab-content` multiple times... rather than for each `tab-content`

Comment: Yes i just noticed. Sorry for bieng wrong @smerny . I changed it though.. And made a note about it